# Failure to connect to Google Assistant

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, error-code

Im attempting to connect my RPi with the following, however it ails, error code 400.  Have looked for an obvious cause, checked the google account, as far as I can tell all ok.  Other google samples work fine, so audio is good; just the following is an issue.

Thanks

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id GoogleAssistant-PiHAT --device-model-id SPKR_MY
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i found the issue, typo in the project name....  thanks

Comment: Hi RDW. I suggest you format your error message using the a Markdown Code fence, 3 backticks ``` at the beginning and 3 backticks ``` at the end. It will be much easier to read.